# Zend methods / library in cron

Tags: zend-framework, url, cron

Is it possible to create an instance of zend_view in a cron tab script in zend?
What i want is to get the base url, server url within a script that is executed by the cron?

I heard that in cron tab, zend_view has no idea of the base and server url.

Is there another way for it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller name CronController  add any action let say

```
Class CronController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
   public function workAction()
   {

         $view = $this->view ; //access for zend_view
   }
}
```

In your crontab use wget to execute your controller action

```
wget -q --spider http://www.mysite.com/public/cron/work
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Cron.php file like this wherever you want :

```
// address of zend library
set_include_path( '../library' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path() ); 

include_once('Zend/Http/Client.php');

$url = 'http://www.yoursite.com/index/cron';

$client = new Zend_Http_Client($url);

$response = $client->request('GET');
```

So you have cronAction and view in index Controller